# webbrowser navigate with proxy internet connection

Tags: vb6, navigation, postdata

If navigate is done with postData, in a pc with proxy internet connection, it is not navigating. any solution ?

```
(web.WebBrowser1.Navigate buildURL, 4 + 8, , byte_array)
```

[image]

Comment: First question, is it navigating on any PC? Secondly have you got Service Pack 6 installed? This solved alot of issues for me. Thirdly sometimes the UAC of the PC (especially Windows 7) caused issues. Check the UAC is basically off and test that.

Comment: Yes it works properly in all PC. But in a PC with proxy internet it does not work. But without postData it works in pc with proxy internet also.